# Upper semicontinuity , a analysis problem.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I have a upper semicontinuous function, $L:X\to\mathbb{R}$, and exists $x\in X$ with the following property:

> There exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that for every $\delta>0$, there exists $y\in U$ such that $L(y)<\delta$.

**My problem**:

I'd like to see that $ L (x) =  0$

Comment: You can't. $$L(z) = \begin{cases}1 &, z = x\\ 0 &, z \neq x\end{cases}$$ is upper semicontinuous (at least if $X$ is a $T_1$ space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not true. Let $L$ be the [indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $\{0\}$; then $L$ is upper semicontinuous, and for each $\delta>0$ and open nbhd $U$ of $0$ there is a $y\in U$ such that $L(y)=0<\delta$, but $L(0)=1$.

**Added:** Worse, let $L:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a continuous positive function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}L(x)=0$; then $U=\Bbb R$ is a nbhd of **every** $x\in\Bbb R$ on which $L$ takes arbitrarily small positive values.

To make the $U$ condition interesting, you probably have to strengthen it to say that $x$ has arbitrarily small nbhds on which $L$ takes arbitrarily small positive values. If you make that change and further take $L$ to be **lower** semicontinuous, you can prove under the stated hypothesis that $L(x)\le 0$. By [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity#Formal_definition) for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an open nbhd $V_\epsilon$ of $x$ such that $L(y)\ge L(x)-\epsilon$ for all $y\in V_\epsilon$. If $L(x)>0$, take $\epsilon=\frac12L(x)$, and take an open $U$ such that $x\in U\subseteq V_\epsilon$ and $L$ takes arbitrarily small positive values on $U$ in order to get a contradiction. (Specifically, there is a $y\in U$ such that $L(y)<\epsilon$.)

Comment: In case  mentioned where you made additional assumptions, the result would be valid if we assume $L (x)\geq 0$, and $f$ lower semicontinuous??

Comment: @OEmpaladordeCabras: Yes, it would: adding $L(x)\ge 0$ to the extra assumption on the nbhds $U$ and changing upper to lower semicontinuity allows you to conclude that $L(x)=0$.

Comment: I would like to see, can you kindly show me?]

Comment: @OEmpaladordeCabras: The proof is already in the added part of my answer: that argument shows that $L(x)\le 0$, and if you know that $L(x)\ge 0$, the only possibility is that $L(x)=0$.